# How do external functions return data in Regina Rexx?

Tags: function, cygwin, external, rexx

I've installed the Regina Rexx package (version 3.9.1) in Cygwin on Windows 10. To test it out, I wrote the following code:

caller:

```
#!/usr/bin/rexx
x = 'callee'() ; say 'callee returned' x ; exit
```

callee:

```
#!/usr/bin/rexx
say 'In callee' ; return 42
```

When I invoke caller, I expect to see:

```
> ./caller
In callee
callee returned 42
```

And in fact, this is exactly what I *do* see when both execs are in my current directory. However, when I move them to a different directory in $PATH and invoke caller, I see:

```
> ./caller
caller returned In callee
```

This was ... unexpected. If there's an explanation of the behavior in the Regina Rexx manual, I'm not seeing it. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to ask this on one of the Regina REXX forums on SourceForge; the response may be quicker.(To be fair, this is probably the first Regina question I've seen on SO.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that Rexx execs can be used as external functions only if they reside in a directory mentioned in the REGINA_MACROS variable, like so:

```
export REGINA_MACROS="${HOME}/subdir:/maybe/somewhere/else"
```

Without this, the called routine is treated as just another executable. The return value is all stdout lines with a space delimiter between them. Any stderr output is sent to the screen (or redirected) as usual.

Comment: [Here](https://comp.lang.rexx.narkive.com/G2FTlwd4/regina-win32-regina-macros) are some details.